# ssllabs.com IPv6 issue: Unable to connect to the server (nginx)

Tags: nginx, ipv6

This error drives me crazy: Running nginx on Debian Buster. ipv4 works fine, but testing with ipv6 throws:

```
Unable to connect to the server
```

`AAAA` Record is available and valid. Connection with `http://ipv6-test.com` and with Powershell (`Test-NetConnection`) from a DualStack Host was not successful.

Version check with `nginx -V`:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.14.2
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-dav-ext --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-subs-filter
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` looks like

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
}
```

`netstat -tulpn` says

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      656/nginx: master p
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      656/nginx: master p
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      656/nginx: master p
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      656/nginx: master p
```

Firewall is open `ufw status`:

```
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Assistance very appreachiated!

Comment: Was `AAAA` record created in DNS? Or how you're testing

Comment: Does your server actually have global IPv6 connectivity? It seems like you asked about this before, but did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue solved. OSI-Layer 8 Issue

[image]

Missconfiguration of `/etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg`

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: Missconfiguration of /etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg

Comment: That doesn't really say what the problem was, so it isn't useful for anyone. You can delete the question if you don't want to share any details.

Comment: That's possible candidate for most useless answer ever.

Comment: Well I have this problem too. Thanks for sharing zero information about how you solved it. :/

Comment: @Gill-Bates when you say "misconfiguration", and nothing else… that doesn't tell anyone anything. Could you elaborate?

Comment: StackExchange does not allow to delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, ensure the basics:

- you have A/AAAA records correctly pointed
- your nginx is listening on ipv6 (as of some ancient version, like 1.11 or so, ivp6 is baked in by default so there's no need to compile it explicitly)
- which firewall might be f'n you up. You usually have iptables or ufw

In my case it was the simplest thing: ufw

do

`$ sudo ufw status`

See if it explicitly allows port 80/443.

In my case it stated:

```shell
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

To fix:
`$ sudo ufw allow http && sudo ufw allow https`

Then do a `$ sudo ufw status` again. You need a minimum of

```shell
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Then do the `ssllabs.com` test again.